# Installing gem MySQL failed

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, libraries

I'm installing mysql gem on Amazon AMI 2010.11.1 and I'm having the next problem:

```
# gem install  mysql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_ssl_set()... no
checking for rb_str_set_len()... no
checking for rb_thread_start_timer()... no
checking for mysql.h... no
checking for mysql/mysql.h... no


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

I think that I have all the needed libs

```
# rpm -qa mysql*
mysql-libs-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.i386
mysql-devel-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.i386
mysql-5.1.47-1.2.amzn1.i386

# rpm -qa ruby*
ruby-irb-1.8.7.302-1.2.amzn1.noarch
ruby-libs-1.8.7.302-1.2.amzn1.i686
ruby-1.8.7.302-1.2.amzn1.i686
ruby-devel-1.8.7.302-1.2.amzn1.i686
ruby-rdoc-1.8.7.302-1.2.amzn1.noarch
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setup was missing gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already run "gem update" and "gem upgrade" first? What OS are you using?